# Using "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE" to load csv file that contains Accented Characters

Tags: mysql, jdbc, load-data-infile

I'm using JDBC to execute query "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE" to load csv file into mysql table.

The csv file contains Accented characters like ä,ö,ü,ß.

My issue is that German characters couldn't insert into mysql table by executing query "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE" through either JDBC or terminal; however, I can insert German characters by executing "INSERT" or "UPDATE" statements.

I have been trying all different ways to figure it out as following, but still couldn't work:

For JDBC connection I did:

```
jdbc:mysql://${sequence.db.svr}/seq?  connectTimeout=20000&amp;useUnicode=yes&amp;characterEncoding=utf8
```

For "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE" I did:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE fileName 
INTO TABLE tableName 
CHARACTER SET UTF8
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"';



String query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '" + fileName +
            "' INTO TABLE pde." + table +
            " CHARACTER SET UTF8" +
            "  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','" +
            " ENCLOSED BY '\"'" 
            + ";";
```

For mysql database property I did:

```
ALTER DATABASE databaseName CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

For mysql table property I did:

```
ALTER TABLE tableName CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Create table query:

```
CREATE TABLE `testTable` (
  `value` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mapped_value` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Create database query:

```
CREATE DATABASE `testDatabase` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci */
```

Csv file:

```
amÜ,amman
amàn,amman
```

CSV file in hex:

```
616d dc2c 616d 6d61 6e0a 616d e06e 2c61 6d6d 616e 0a
```

Comment: **1)** Use this at the beginning: `SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'; SET collation_connection = 'utf8_general_ci'`, and **2)** Check that your input file is created in the right encoding (use `enca` or `file -i`)

Comment: @Alfabravo  you are right. My csv file is in incorrect encoding. I fixed this bug by changing the csv file encoding to utf8. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks to me like your CSV file is coded in Latin-1 (ISO 8859-1) rather than utf-8.  How can I tell this?

```
 a  m   Ü  ,   a  m   m  a   n  \n    a  m   à  n   ,  a   m  m   a  n   \n

61 6d  dc 2c  61 6d  6d 61  6e 0a    61 6d  e0 6e  2c 61  6d 6d  61 6e   0a
```

See how  Ü  is coded by just one byte, `dc`?  That's Latin-1.  If it were in utf-8 it would be coded by `c39c` instead.

So change `CHARACTER SET UTF8` in your `LOAD DATA INFILE` command to `CHARACTER SET latin1` and try again.

Comment: Thanks! You are right. My csv file is in incorrect encoding. I fixed this bug by changing the csv file encoding to utf8. Thanks!

Comment: Liked this explanation to deduce encoding.

Answer (score -1):

CSV file is enconding in ANSI or other format no UTF8.
Try this: Use Notepad++ (code editor) to change the encoding.
In Notepad++ go to ENCODING menu --> Convert to UTF-8
and then Save As. Try again using load data local infile.